# Restore xen image deleted with xen-delete-image

Tags: xen

I deleted a xen image using xen-delete-image and was wondering if there's a way in which I can restore this since 'xen-delete-image' only removes it from the list of xen images but doesn't delete the actual image files (disk.img and swap.img).
Is there a command to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folowing procedure has worked for me, provided that the image is not corrupted in any way.

Using the gui, I created a new server, named it differently from the original one, and created a new drive image with the same capacity as the deleted server.

I cancelled the installation at the first chance, leaving a virtual server without a bootable os.

After this I stopped the server, and overwrote the image I just created with the image of the deleted server (naming it identically to the new image).

All I had to reset where the network settings...

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best thing to do is to copy the existing disk.img and swap.img out of the way, create a new instance using xen-create-image and move the original img files back over the new ones. You may need to set some config options like the block device names and mac address to to old values before it boots correctly.

Comment: I already tried that but when loading it gets stuck at some point with the message "Waiting for root file system"

Comment: Sounds like the block device name is wrong. Try changing hd to sd in the xen config file or vis versa.

Comment: Hey thanks david, tried this as well but still no luck